# Grouping Parametrized Benchmarks with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm currently benchmarking an implementation of an AVL Tree I made against a non-rebalancing binary search tree using [pytest-benchmark](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-benchmark).  It seems to be working well for me so far but I've run into an issue.  In order to consolidate the test file, I found that I can [parametrize tests](http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html) and also [group the output of the benchmark](https://pytest-benchmark.readthedocs.org/en/stable/usage.html#markers) for readability but I can't seem to do them both at the same time.

My current insertion benchmark:

```
# always the same for repeatability
random.seed(0x1C2C6D66)

def insertRandomOrder(t, n):
  tree = t()
  for i in range(0,n):
    tree.insert(random.randint(0,0x7FFFFFFF),i)

def insertDescendingOrder(t, n):
  tree = t()
  for i in range(0,n):
    tree.insert(n-i,i)

def insertOutInOrder(t, n):
  tree = t()
  for i in range(0,n):
    idx = (i%2)*n + (1-2*(i%2))*i
    tree.insert(idx,i)

def insertAscendingOrder(t, n):
  tree = t()
  for i in range(0,n):
    tree.insert(i,i)

types = [BaseTree, AvlTree]
sizes = [100,300,1000]
cases = [insertAscendingOrder, insertDescendingOrder, insertOutInOrder, insertRandomOrder]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('t', types)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('n', sizes)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('case', cases)
def test_insert_benchmark(benchmark, t, n, case):
  benchmark(case, t, n)
```

And here is the output:

[image: output from parametrized pytest-benchmark run]

Does anyone know of a way where I could group the output but say, the `case` from my example?  Or better yet, by a `(case,n)` tuple?

Comment: There is support for specific param grouping in the master branch.

Just `pip install https://github.com/ionelmc/pytest-benchmark/archive/master.zip` and then use `--benchmark-group-by=param:case`.

I think we could support the `case,n` situation ...

Comment: I did see the param option, but didn't know about the `:<param_name>` option in the main branch.  I get an unrelated error in the master branch, though when I try to run the benchmark.  "File "xxx\python35\lib\site-packages\pytest_benchmark\storage.py line 41 `if candidate.is_file():`", "OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*'" (running on Windows 10... work computer.  I'll try again when I get home on my preferred Linux Dev Environment)

Comment: FYI, I've fixed the Windows issue and you can have `--benchmark-group-by=param:foo,param:bar` now (in master branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was [a useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110308/grouping-the-output-of-a-parametrized-benchmarks-with-pytest#comment58019280_35110308) saying that the master branch of pytest is in the process of supporting this exact feature, but I was unable to get it to work (fingers crossed for next release).

In the meantime, I figured out this handy work around.  I'm able to group by `case`, but not by `(case,n)` with this method.  I added a `@benchmark_this` decorator above each test case to wrap the `benchmark` call.  It's pretty handy even without the extra benefit of grouping by test case!

```
def benchmark_this(test):
  def wrapper(benchmark, t, n):
    benchmark(test, None, t, n)
  return wrapper

types = [BaseTree, AvlTree]
sizes = [100,300,1000]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('t', types)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('n', sizes)
@benchmark_this
def test_insertRandomOrder(benchmark, t, n):
  random.seed(0x1C2C6D66)
  tree = t()
  for i in range(n):
    tree.insert(random.randint(0, 0x7FFFFFFF), i)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('t', types)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('n', sizes)
@benchmark_this
def test_insertDescendingOrder(benchmark, t, n):
  tree = t()
  for i in range(n):
    tree.insert(n-i, i)

# ...
```

Invoked with

> py.test --benchmark-group-by=func

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, (it's not documented anywhere, but as per the code, and my tests) we can programmatically assign the group by using

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", [1, 2, 3])
@pytest.mark.benchmark(group="Some prefix:")
def test_some_name(param, benchmark):
    benchmark.group += f"{param = }"
    ... rest of code ...
```

This has been the case for at least 9 years (since 2015, 3.0 release) as of 2024 (4.0 release)