# Runtime statistics for parallel test function calls (with pytest-benchmark or some other plugin)

Tags: python, statistics, pytest, benchmarking, pytest-parallel

I want to use a plugin like `pytest-benchmark` to show me runtime **statistics for the parallel calls**
`test_valid_submission(0)`, ..., `test_valid_submission(EXPERIMENT_SIZE)`.

For this, I have the following code, which tries to achieve this using `pytest-benchmark` (similar to [Grouping Parametrized Benchmarks with pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110308/grouping-parametrized-benchmarks-with-pytest)):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("counter", range(EXPERIMENT_SIZE))
def test_performance_under_load(benchmark, counter):
    benchmark(test_valid_submission, counter)
```

When I call

```
pytest --workers auto --tests-per-worker auto -vv --benchmark-only --benchmark-verbose --group-by=func
```

I hoped to get [a benchmark summary table](https://warehouse-camo.ingress.cmh1.psfhosted.org/24d595bb08e7485da7d9759be214551482b5b15e/68747470733a2f2f6769746875622e636f6d2f696f6e656c6d632f7079746573742d62656e63686d61726b2f7261772f6d61737465722f646f63732f73637265656e73686f742e706e67) at the end,
with min, max, mean, standard deviation for each runtime of my `EXPERIMENT_SIZE` parallel `test_valid_submission()` calls. Unfortunately, no benchmark summary table is printed (see details below).

@hoefling commented that `pytest-benchmark` doesn't support running and collecting benchmark data in parallel.

Is there another pytest plugin (or other solution) that can

- collect the `EXPERIMENT_SIZE` number of parallel `test_valid_submission(x)` calls and group them together
- compute min, max, mean, standard deviation for the runtime statistics of the parallel calls in the group
- use multiple groups, e.g. one for `test_valid_submission(x)` and one for `test_invalid_submission(x)`
- print the statistics at the end of my tests, similar to the [pytest-benchmark summary table mentioned above](https://warehouse-camo.ingress.cmh1.psfhosted.org/24d595bb08e7485da7d9759be214551482b5b15e/68747470733a2f2f6769746875622e636f6d2f696f6e656c6d632f7079746573742d62656e63686d61726b2f7261772f6d61737465722f646f63732f73637265656e73686f742e706e67)?

#### Details about pytest-benchmark

With `pytest-benchmark`, `EXPERIMENT_SIZE=3`, `iterations=1` and `rounds=1`, I get the following output (but even when `EXPERIMENT_SIZE>=5`, it shows `rounds=5` and no statistics).

but I get the following output (with `EXPERIMENT_SIZE=3` and irrelevant lines removed):

> ```
>  ============================== test session starts ==========================================
>  platform linux -- Python 3.6.10, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /anaconda3/envs/reg/bin/python
>  benchmark: 3.2.3 (defaults: timer=time.perf_counter disable_gc=False min_rounds=5 min_time=0.000005 max_time=1.0 calibration_precision=10 warmup=False warmup_iterations=100000)
>  plugins: repeat-0.8.0, cov-2.8.1, bdd-3.2.1, clarity-0.3.0a0, benchmark-3.2.3, parallel-0.1.0
>  collected 22 items
>  pytest-parallel: 8 workers (processes), 3 tests per worker (threads)
>
>  ...
>
>  test/test_x.py::test_valid_submission SKIPPED
>
> Computing precision for time.perf_counter ... 50.99ns.
>
> Calibrating to target round 5.00us; will estimate when reaching 2.50us (using: time.perf_counter, precision: 50.99ns).
>
> Computing precision for time.perf_counter ... 48.98ns.
>
> Calibrating to target round 5.00us; will estimate when reaching 2.50us (using: time.perf_counter, precision: 48.98ns).
>
> Computing precision for time.perf_counter ... 49.01ns.
>
> Calibrating to target round 5.00us; will estimate when reaching
> 2.50us (using: time.perf_counter, precision: 49.01ns).
>
> Measured 1 iterations: 105.72s.   Running 5 rounds x 1 iterations ...
> Measured 1 iterations: 105.73s.   Running 5 rounds x 1 iterations ...
> Measured 1 iterations: 117.20s.   Running 5 rounds x 1 iterations ...   
> Ran for 339.53s.   Ran for 350.11s.   Ran for 461.53s.
>
> test/test_x.py::test_performance_under_load[2] PASSED
> test/test_x.py::test_performance_under_load[1] PASSED
> test/test_x.py::test_performance_under_load[0] PASSED
>
> ========================== 3 passed, 19 skipped in 714.05s (0:11:54) ========================
> ```

Using alternatively `benchmark.pedantic(test_valid_submission, args=[counter], iterations=1, rounds=1)` does not lead do printed statistics either.

Comment: The link you posted leads to shorturl.at. I suppose it displayed the `benchmark`s summary table?

Comment: `benchmark` doesn't support running and collecting benchmark data in parallel, and TBH I don't see a quick fix for that, one would have to mess with the plugin's internals.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for your comment, now I put the focus more on an alternative to pytest-benchmark. Do you know one?

Comment: @hoefling: Can you post as an answer? (Also, how to keep this on-topic for SO and not a package recommendation question). DaveFar: suggest you raise an issue on https://github.com/ionelmc/pytest-benchmark/issues